# how to trigger an event on change in the text editor

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on an application using c++ and Qtcreator. I want to trigger an event whenever text change in the text editor. There can be a change in font size or font-weight

Answer (score 0):

You do that by using signal-slot system. Provided that you're using QTextEdit,  it would be something along lines:

```
connect(textEdit, &QTextEdit::currentCharFormatChanged,
        this, &TextEdit::currentCharFormatChanged);
connect(textEdit, &QTextEdit::cursorPositionChanged,
        this, &TextEdit::cursorPositionChanged);

connect(textEdit->document(), &QTextDocument::modificationChanged,
        actionSave, &QAction::setEnabled);
connect(textEdit->document(), &QTextDocument::modificationChanged,
        this, &QWidget::setWindowModified);
```

Actually, Qt offers an example of application in `examples/widgets/richtext/textedit`